# Cannot access files from xunit in WinRT (The process has no package identity)

Tags: file-io, windows-runtime, xunit, xunit.net

I'm writing some unit tests (with **xunit**) to my **WinRT** project.

I have prepared text file with json content. I put this file into my Test project and now I want to read file, parse json and check some stuff. It's working for MS Test but failing for xUnit.

When I run test writen with **xUnit** I receive:

System.InvalidOperationException
The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)

```C#
[Fact]
public async Task ProjectFile()
{
    var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    folder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("SampleData");

    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("companies.txt");
    Assert.NotNull(file);

    var result = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    Assert.True(result.Length > 0);
}
```

My IDE:

- Visual Studio 2012 Pro Update 3
- WinRT project
- ReSharper 7.1.3
- xUnit

Anyone can help here?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but xUnit.net 1.x did not officially support anything but desktop libraries.

xUnit.net 2.x supports:

- Desktop
- Portable (Profile 259)
- DNX (.NET and .NET Core, including ASP.NET 5+)
- Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight)
- Windows Universal (Windows Phone 8.1+, Windows 8.1+)
- Xamarin (MonoAndroid, MonoTouch, and iOS Universal)

Presumably one of these platforms is something you're targeting. ;)